# Index is not being used on a partitioned table

Tags: database, oracle, performance, indexing, partitioning

I have `tableA`, which is (list) partitioned almost evenly by 5 values. `tableA` contains 100million rows and has a local (partitioned) index on `customFunc(x)`. Following query does `RANGE SCAN` using mentioned index and takes about 5-10s to execute and returns 5million.

```
select count(*) from tableA where customFunc(x)='abc';
```

Unfortunately, when I try to execute the same query on a specific partition it does full table scan and takes forever..

```
select count(*) from tableA where customFunc(x)='abc' and partitioning_key='DT';
```

I completely don't understand why it works that way.. Shouldn't it take an advantage of partition pruning in the 2nd case?

EDIT:  Adding a hint `/*+ index(tableA mentionedIndex) */` solves the problem, but I still don't understand why it is not used by default

EDIT: XPLAN 1

```
Plan hash value: xxx

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                               |     1 |    17 | 29335   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE     |                               |     1 |    17 |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST ALL|                               |  5227K|    84M| 29335   (1)| 00:00:02 |     1 |     5 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN | CUSTOM_FUNC_INDEX             |  5227K|    84M| 29335   (1)| 00:00:02 |     1 |     5 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access(customFunc(x)='abc')
```

XPLAN 2 (with partition key)

```
Plan hash value: yyy

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           |     1 |    30 |   679K  (2)| 00:00:27 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |           |     1 |    30 |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE|           |  4014K|   114M|   679K  (2)| 00:00:27 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | tableA    |  4014K|   114M|   679K  (2)| 00:00:27 |     1 |     1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(customFunc(x)='abc')
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  Multiple factors are involved in the optimizer's decision-making, including the statistics, resources available, indexes, etc.  Seeing the optimizer plans for these two queries would be useful.  Could you add the xplans to the question?

Comment: the [`10053 trace`](http://www.centrexcc.com/A%20Look%20under%20the%20Hood%20of%20CBO%20-%20the%2010053%20Event.pdf) is your friend is such situations...

Comment: @alexgibbs please see above plans, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that helps.  Looks like it is using the partition, just not with the index--I'm not confident enough to answer just yet and will experiment a bit with this, but from the cardinalities in these plans, I would wonder if the optimizer sees the index as not sufficiently selective in that partition and opts for full instead.  It would be interesting to see if the behavior is the same with different predicates--`customFunc(x)='VOLTRON'` or whatever instead of `'abc'`, and what the histograms are like.

Comment: Stuart just a follow-up here.  I wondered if you could check on the relative cardinality of the 'abc' predicate withinin the target partition.  Does this query fetch a lot of the target partition?  Presuming up-to-date stats, histos, etc.(nothing is stale?), it would be good to see if a data skew could be involved here.  Does a zero-match predicate on customFunc(x) also do a full scan?  Thanks

Comment: Please post the explain plan for the query with the `/*+ index */` hint.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it take an advantage of partition pruning in the 2nd case?

The second query *does* apply partition pruning: that's what this step means:  `PARTITION LIST SINGLE` . The catch is that partition pruning means reading the whole partition: in the second plan the step `TABLE ACCESS FULL` means read all the rows in the partition, don't use an index. Consequently, the second query is evaluating `customFunc(x)='abc'` for every row in the partition.

> What is the point of creating a local index with partitioning key?

The difference is that a local index prefixed with the partitioning key will always use partition pruning, whereas when a local index doesn't have the partitioning key the optimiser can choose whether to apply partition pruning. But if you want to run queries that don't use the partition key then clearly you need the non-prefixed version.

Now you're right to be puzzled. Given the partition key as a predicate the optimizer *ought* to have executed an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` against the indicated partition. To figure out why it doesn't will require more effort on your part. It may be that your statistics are stale or you need to gather histograms. Maybe the fact that it's a function-based index confuses the optimizer. If you have the access, or a co-operative DBA, you can use the 10053 event to look under the hood. [Find out more](http://www.centrexcc.com/A%20Look%20under%20the%20Hood%20of%20CBO%20-%20the%2010053%20Event.pdf).

Comment: index was build using "create index indexname on tableA (customFunc(x)) local"
why is oracle using this index when I search every partition and not when i search a specific one? What is the point of creating a local index with partitioning key?

Comment: btw: when I force cob to use the index it works like a charm

Comment: Does the function the function do anything explicit with the Partition key? I guess not.

Comment: @Stuart Thanks APC. I was under the impression and believe I have observed that with local non-prefixed indexes, separate predicates on partition keys can be used independently and in conjunction with local indexes on other cols. Though  possible to probe all partitions when not given the partition key, I believe the optimizer has the option to make use of both partition-pruning and index access, when both predicates where present.  Thanks    https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-A43726D5-300D-4F5E-8FF3-85F057BC4CD3.htm#VLDBG1263

Comment: @alexgibbs - the pertinent point is that *"the optimizer has the option"*. Sometimes when given options the optimizer makes the wrong choice. That's what seems to be happening here. Usually we would expect the optimizer to choose partition elimination and index range scan. So there's no obvious reason why it doesn't in this case.